# Is it legal to include .Net framework in my custom installer ( not using VS installer)

Tags: .net, redistributable

I'm developing a custom .Net Application Installer, and I'm wondering if is it legal to include the .Net framework  in my application (Redistributable .net framework installer)
Version 2.0 at least.

Comment: No problem why should they (MS) disallow this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about law, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you follow their license terms you should be able to do it.

[Redistributing the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xak0tsbd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

The other alternative would be to direct the user to the internet to download the installer themselves. If file size is of any concern, then this might be advantageous, as it would also reduce the size of your packaged application (you don't have to provide the redistributable installer).